# Replace a sub-vector of a row in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace all the occurrences of say `c(0,0)` in two given columns, say `c("x","y")`, of a dataframe `df` by say `c(-99, -1)`.

```
df = data.frame(
   x = c(0, 0:6),
   y = c(0, 0:6),
   z = 10:17
)
df
##   x y  z
## 1 0 0 10
## 2 0 0 11
## 3 1 1 12
## 4 2 2 13
## 5 3 3 14
## 6 4 4 15
## 7 5 5 16
## 8 6 6 17
```

In `df`, the colums `c("x","y")` have two pairs of 0, so these pairs would have to be replaced, every `x`s by `-99` and every `y` by `-1`. The result should be in that case:

```
##     x  y  z
## 1 -99 -1 10
## 2 -99 -1 11
## 3   1  1 12
## 4   2  2 13
## 5   3  3 14
## 6   4  4 15
## 7   5  5 16
## 8   6  6 17
```

The pairs to search, `c(0,0)` and the replacement pair `c(-99,-1)` must be arguments that can be modified.
Locating their presence if easy:

```
if (any(df[,c("x","y")]==c(0,0))) {
    warning("Imputing...")
}
```

but from there, I am a bit at a lost. I could loop over all the lines of the data frame, but there should be a more compact solution? (preferable using base R only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
df[with(df, x == 0 & y == 0), c("x", "y")] <- list(-99, -1)
```

which gives

```
> df
    x  y  z
1 -99 -1 10
2 -99 -1 11
3   1  1 12
4   2  2 13
5   3  3 14
6   4  4 15
7   5  5 16
8   6  6 17
```

Comment: As as an addition: it is possible to replace x and y with different values with `df[with(df, x == 0 & y == 0), c("x", "y")] <- c(0,-1)`. Thanks

Comment: However, if there are two or more lines that satisfies the criteria, the replacement are done vertically, i.e., to replace with `c(0,1)`, the columns will be filled with alternations of 0s and 1s. The 0s will not all be in one column and the 1s in the other column. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @DenisCousineau could you elaborate that case in your question? I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: See my edits in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

easy solution to change x and y respectively to -99 and -1 if both values contain 0

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(x = case_when(x == 0 & y == 0 ~ -99,
                       T ~ x),
         y = case_when(x == 0 & y == 0 ~ -1,
                       T ~ y))
```

Comment: It seems that it always requires a two-step modification to the data frame?

Comment: yes, it is impossible to change two columns in one step